# Coral Dev Board - edgetpu_demo: command not found

Tags: google-coral

Today I started to use my Coral Dev Board and followed [these instructions](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/).
When I try to run the [demo app](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#run-demo) with `edgetpu_demo --stream`, I get the following error message:

`-bash: edgetpu_demo: command not found`

Running a model using the PyCoral API works fine.

Is there a new command for the demo app or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `edgetpu_demo` command does not work because the [Edge TPU API is deprecated](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/api-intro/#install-the-library). The Get started with the Dev Board guide is out of date in this case because the necessary modules to execute `edgetpu` commands are not installed.

[Here](https://coral.ai/software/#debian-packages) you can find the packages that would have to be installed manually afterwards. However, these can no longer be installed from the official sources. Instead you could install the old packages from the [archive](https://coral.ai/software/#alternative-packages).

Note: The Edge TPU API has been replaced by the [PyCoral API](https://coral.ai/docs/reference/py/) and should be preferred instead.

Answer (score 0):

Edgepu_demo uses [edgetpuvision API](https://coral.googlesource.com/edgetpuvision/+/refs/heads/master/edgetpuvision/detect.py), which got updated to pycoral API. Please reflash the board with the latest [image](https://coral.ai/software/#mendel-dev-board) you would be able to run the edgetpu_demo.